# Typescript: Not all constituents of type are callable even though I check for typeof 'function'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a simple data store with typescript. When setting the store I want to do something like react where if you pass in a function you can get the previous store and return the value you want to be stored. But in doing so I get the following error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '((store: T) => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.
```

This error happens in the `setStore()` function when calling `newStore(store)`. I am not sure why though because I am checking the typeof newStore to make sure it is a function before calling it. So you would think that typescript would infer at that point that the type of newStore is indeed a callable function.

Here is the code [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgShYBXATgOwgEwDwwHxQC8UA2gFBSVQAUAlEQTADQVXUYDuAysAPYoQAXLCgAfGtQDOfAcJj1CjWgoIA3XgEtMLALpkyAMyRoAxsA280UEwICGwCABF7tnvwi48UmUNj05CMjoWJ5QAN6slEam5pZQAOaIbgJ04ZFUlAJBVtLu6QC%20%20hnRZhY5ST7sENw%20cmISubJ%20DH70ERkZjdDEoJC8BlCcyd2ExADkJbFoY1AA-IPVw97u-gs1eRmF6VmoViSJwMNMUJIV7nr5UPomltKkBwDCvMbAx6fATy86RNZ2Ds7AVw%20bBoJAAWwARhAUF4AIy0fRkd6fNDAajLJqgyHQlRpDI7dAnHxQADUUFhZHyCLINzQkl4ABsIAA6Bm8eLUR7PVF0WhAA)

```
type TReturned<T> = [
    () => T,
    (newStore: T | ((store: T) => T)) => void,
]

function createDataStore<T>(store: T) : TReturned<T> {
    function getStore() {
        return store
    }

    function setStore(newStore: T | ((store: T) => T)) {
        // Error happens here when calling newStore(store)
        store = typeof newStore === 'function' ? newStore(store) : newStore
    }

    return [getStore, setStore]
} 

const [getCount, setCount] = createDataStore<number>(1)


setCount((store: number) => {
    return store + 1
})

console.log(getCount())
```

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#37663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663); if `T` is itself a function type, then `T & Function` might not be callable with just `store` as an input.  It's an unlikely problem that the compiler is warning about, so you might want to just assert and move on.  See the answer to the linked question for more information.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I don't know why this didn't pop up in google or in the suggestions when I asked the question.

Comment: It didn't pop up when I googled for it either, I just remembered I had recently answered a question about it and started scrolling through my answers.